# In CanvasJS chart add one month on the dates

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

When I'm trying to use CanvasJS chart I found that the script add automatically 1 month on the whole dates in X-Axis ...
In the beginning I thought that there is a problem in my code but I found the same problem in the website online examples ...
check the below URL and note the dates in the code and how it's generated in the chart:
http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/date-time-axis/

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug: the month parameter of the Date() function takes values 0..11, not 1..12 as I suspect you are assuming.